# Insert axis labels in Jasper Reports

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I am studying Java with Jasper Reports and I am trying to create a report with a `XYLineChart`

My report is ok all the data is showing the way I want. My chart is plotting all the data but the X and Y axis do not have a name (`label`) so I can not "know" what that data is.

I wanna to put the names of my axis in the chart. I did some reading and find this in a book:

> The Line plot also has two axes. Their labels can be controlled by using the categoryAxisLabelExpression and valueAxisLabelExpression...

The book gives the the syntax below:

```
<!ELEMENT linePlot (plot, categoryAxisLabelExpression?,
categoryAxisFormat?, valueAxisLabelExpression?, valueAxisFormat?)>

<!ATTLIST linePlot
isShowLines (true | false) "true"
isShowShapes (true | false) "true">
```

The `jrxml` complete code is in my GitHub: [Report](https://github.com/johnnyarza/controle_test_cp/blob/master/reports/CompresionTestReport.jrxml)

Below there are the lines,extracted from the code above, about the `chart`:

```
</band>
        <band height="164">
            <xyLineChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="20" y="20" width="280" height="144" uuid="e33fd328-3bfa-41f7-aa53-face45efaf74">
                        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.interval"><![CDATA[value]]></propertyExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <xyDataset>
                    <dataset resetType="Report">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="CorpoDeProvaChartDataSet" uuid="320307a6-07d6-4d08-8f42-0537af75c157">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{CorpoDeProvaChartCollectionBeanParam}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <xySeries autoSort="true">
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{serie}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <xValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{days}]]></xValueExpression>
                        <yValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{fck}]]></yValueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA["TEst"]]></labelExpression>
                    </xySeries>
                </xyDataset>
                <linePlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </linePlot>
            </xyLineChart>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="143" y="111" width="100" height="30" uuid="a6f5c887-cac8-4304-b8d5-8b9bb492ee39"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
```

I tried to change my code like this, but It just gives me a error:

```
...
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    <categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Days"]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["fck"]]</valueAxisLabelExpression>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
...
```

Also I could not find anything in the chart's properties tab of Jaspersoft Studio that would do the trick. And any reference I could find points to  `valueAxisLabelExpression` and `valueAxisFormat` properties but I do not know how to set them.

Additional info:

1. I am using Eclipse IDE
2. My report is filled with `subDataSets` with `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` `class`

To summarize I wanna know how to put a `label` in X and Y axis of a `XYLineChart` in JasperReport.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

After some tries and reading I did what I want.

At my first try I've used my `chart` code like this:

```
<categoryAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
    <categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Days"]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
</categoryAxisFormat>
<valueAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["fck"]]</valueAxisLabelExpression></valueAxisFormat>
```

But the correct sintax is:

```
<categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Days"]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
<categoryAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
</categoryAxisFormat>
<valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["fck (MPa)"]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
<valueAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
</valueAxisFormat>
```

So I just had to change the lines order in my code.
Thank you everyone...